# Azure pipeline to build angular JS app Bundle failing - npm ERR! missing script: D:\a\1\s/bundle.js

Tags: angularjs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I am trying to build and publish an angular.js app up to azure blob storage.
I have the project building and I now need to run the bundling task to create an output that I want to publish up to blob storage, but when I run the task I get : npm ERR! missing script: D:\a\1\s/bundle.js

The build step in question is an NPM task and has this YAML :

```
    - task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm bundle'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bundle.js'
```

Any idea how I do the bundling?

Here is the output from the task :

```
    2021-05-24T18:56:12.9880011Z ##[section]Starting: npm bundle
2021-05-24T18:56:13.0035645Z ==============================================================================
2021-05-24T18:56:13.0036045Z Task         : npm
2021-05-24T18:56:13.0036457Z Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and authenticated registries like Azure Artifacts.
2021-05-24T18:56:13.0036887Z Version      : 1.182.0
2021-05-24T18:56:13.0037154Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-05-24T18:56:13.0037500Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm
2021-05-24T18:56:13.0038136Z ==============================================================================
2021-05-24T18:56:13.9312661Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.17.0\x64\npm.cmd --version"
2021-05-24T18:56:14.6978076Z 6.14.13
2021-05-24T18:56:16.3055204Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.17.0\x64\npm.cmd config list"
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0914358Z ; cli configs
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0915201Z metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0915747Z scope = ""
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0916249Z user-agent = "npm/6.14.13 node/v14.17.0 win32 x64"
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0916554Z 
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0916973Z ; environment configs
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0917440Z prefix = "C:\\npm\\prefix"
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0917914Z userconfig = "D:\\a\\1\\npm\\642.npmrc"
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0918226Z 
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0918651Z ; globalconfig C:\npm\prefix\etc\npmrc
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0919191Z cache = "C:\\npm\\cache"
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0919472Z 
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0919966Z ; node bin location = C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.17.0\x64\node.exe
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0920510Z ; cwd = D:\a\1\s
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0920984Z ; HOME = C:\Users\VssAdministrator
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0921466Z ; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0921829Z 
2021-05-24T18:56:17.0924582Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.17.0\x64\npm.cmd run bundle.js"
2021-05-24T18:56:17.9822327Z npm ERR! missing script: bundle.js
2021-05-24T18:56:17.9822972Z 
2021-05-24T18:56:17.9823559Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-05-24T18:56:17.9825738Z npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2021-05-24T18_56_17_954Z-debug.log
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0311838Z Found npm debug log, make sure the path matches with the one in npm's output: C:\npm\cache\_logs\2021-05-24T18_56_17_954Z-debug.log
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0312533Z 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0312918Z 1 verbose cli [
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0313463Z 1 verbose cli   'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\14.17.0\\x64\\node.exe',
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0314045Z 1 verbose cli   'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\14.17.0\\x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0314505Z 1 verbose cli   'run',
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0314812Z 1 verbose cli   'bundle.js'
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0315127Z 1 verbose cli ]
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0315491Z 2 info using npm@6.14.13
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0315798Z 3 info using node@v14.17.0
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0316183Z 4 verbose stack Error: missing script: bundle.js
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0316777Z 4 verbose stack     at run (C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.17.0\x64\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0317478Z 4 verbose stack     at C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.17.0\x64\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0318238Z 4 verbose stack     at C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.17.0\x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:116:5
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0319056Z 4 verbose stack     at C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.17.0\x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:436:5
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0319913Z 4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.17.0\x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:391:45)
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0322803Z 4 verbose stack     at final (C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.17.0\x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:434:3)
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0323664Z 4 verbose stack     at then (C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.17.0\x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:161:5)
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0324498Z 4 verbose stack     at C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.17.0\x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:281:12
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0325369Z 4 verbose stack     at C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.17.0\x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0326349Z 4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:73:3)
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0326818Z 5 verbose cwd D:\a\1\s
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0327158Z 6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0327803Z 7 verbose argv "C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\14.17.0\\x64\\node.exe" "C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\14.17.0\\x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "bundle.js"
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0328421Z 8 verbose node v14.17.0
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0328745Z 9 verbose npm  v6.14.13
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0329098Z 10 error missing script: bundle.js
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0329457Z 11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0329605Z 
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0372730Z ##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
2021-05-24T18:56:18.0394696Z ##[section]Finishing: npm bundle
```

Comment: Might be an issue with the mixing of unix/posix-style paths. I have has issues where gulp fails from mixed path separators. Turn on verbose and see if the command you are expecting is getting sent to npm also share that output here if you still need more help diagnosing. Your task configuration (minus the bad first line indent) looks generally correct. My bet is on the path.

Comment: Added the output from the task above. Also, I am running this on a windows build agent in azure. Should it be unix?

Comment: I wouldn't swap environments just to fix a minor pathing issue, but the output suggests the source code your are downloading does not have a `bundle.js` in the root. Can you verify the commit is what you expect and the filesystem is in the state you expect? I can't recall but I think when you manually trigger a build you can toggle on `enable system diagnostics` and you should get a readout of all the files being cloned on the job init.

Comment: Ok, so I changed the task type to command line, and just running node bundle.js in the script. And that looks like it does something and outputs : 

Generating script.
Script contents:
node bundle.js

Answer (score 1):

Based on your latest comment, the bundle.js file is valid.

You could try the following steps to run js file with NPM Task.

1. Add the **scripts parameters** in Package.json file.

Example:

```
{
  "name": "webpackguide",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "bundle":"node bundle.js"
  },

....
```

2. In NPM task, you could directly call the bundle command:

Example:

```
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm custom'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run bundle'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I changed the task type to a commandline task and just called node bundle.js :

```
steps:
- script: 'node bundle.js'
  displayName: 'Bundle JS'
```